# How to play Minecraft without internet?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How to play Minecraft without connecting to the internet? Is it not possible?

Comment: It is possible. Steps: 1. Turn off your network. 2. Open Minecraft Launcher. 3. Launch your Minecraft version. 4. Play the game offline

Answer (score 0):

You can play without the internet, as long as you are willing to lose some of your data for the day. It will prevent you from buying something from the marketplace, but it works.